# Asymmetric Gaussian Fit in Python

Tags: python, curve-fitting, gaussian

I'm trying to fit an asymmetric Gaussian to this data: http://ge.tt/99iNaL53 (csv file).

I have tried to use a skewed Gaussian model from lmfit, and also a spline, but I'm not able to get the Gaussian model to fit well and the splines are not what I'm looking for (I don't want the spline to fit the data exactly as shown below, and altering the level of smoothing isn't helping).

Here is code using the above data that produces the plot below. The second figure is an example of what I'm trying to achieve with the goal of reading the rise and decay time from the fit.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.interpolate import CubicSpline
from scipy.interpolate import UnivariateSpline
from lmfit.models import SkewedGaussianModel

data = np.loadtxt('data.csv', delimiter=',')

x = data[:,0]
y = data[:,1]

# Skewed Gaussian fit
model = SkewedGaussianModel()
params = model.make_params(amplitude=400, center=3, sigma=7, gamma=1)
result = model.fit(y, params, x=x)

# Cubic Spline
cs = CubicSpline(x, y)
x_range = np.arange(x[0], x[-1], 0.1)

# Univariate Spline
us = UnivariateSpline(x, y, k = 1)

# Univariate Spline (smoothed)
us2 = UnivariateSpline(x, y, k = 5)

plt.scatter(x, y, marker = '^', color = 'k', linewidth = 0.5, s = 10, label = 'data')
plt.plot(x_range, cs(x_range), label = 'Cubic Spline')
plt.plot(x_range, us(x_range), label = 'Univariate Spline, k = 1')
plt.plot(x_range, us2(x_range), label = 'Univariate Spline, k = 5')
plt.plot(x, result.best_fit, color = 'red', label = 'Skewed Gaussian Attempt')
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.yscale('log')
plt.ylim(1,500)
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image: Data and fit attempts]
[image: Example]

Comment: It looks like you may want a beta distribution.  I have some code in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57280577/sensitivity-specificity-plot-python/57317961#57317961) that accomplishes such a thing.  Does that help?

Comment: Late to the discussion, but: you might want to try a lognormal distribution function.

Answer (score 4):

I wrote something for J. Chem. Ed. `[1]` that involved fitting asymmetric Gaussian functions to data, you can find the core repo here `[2]` but below is a snippet on how I went about fitting a `data` set where `x = data[:,0]` and `y = data[:,1]` to the type of function you're working with:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import leastsq
from scipy.special import erf

initials = [6.5, 13, 1, 0] # initial guess

def asymGaussian(x, p):
    amp = (p[0] / (p[2] * np.sqrt(2 * np.pi)))
    spread = np.exp((-(x - p[1]) ** 2.0) / (2 * p[2] ** 2.0))
    skew = (1 + erf((p[3] * (x - p[1])) / (p[2] * np.sqrt(2))))
    return amp * spread * skew

def residuals(p,y,x):
    return y - asymGaussian(x, p)

# executes least-squares regression analysis to optimize initial parameters
cnsts = leastsq(
    residuals, 
    initials, 
    args=(
        data_set[:,1], # y value
        data_set[:,0]  # x value
        ))[0]

y = asymGaussian(data[:,0], cnsts)
```

finally just plot `(y, data[:,0])`. Hope this helps!

```
[1] https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/acs.jchemed.9b00818
[2] https://github.com/1mikegrn/pyGC
```

Comment: Thank you for this - it gives a very similar curve to the red 'skewed gaussian attempt' in my plot above, however. I guess having a good fit at low y and high x may not be possible, and like the comment below notes, is just amplified visually due to the log scale.

Answer (score 3):

Is there a question here?  I don't see one, actually.

That result from `lmfit` *is* the best fit to a skewed Gaussian model.
You've chosen to plot the result on a log-scale. That completely changes the view of the quality of the fit or what is not fit well.

It seems like you're expecting a better fit, but not **too* good.  Well, it looks like your data is not perfectly represented by a single skewed Gaussian.  It seems like you were not expecting it to be.  You could try different forms for the model function, say a skewed Lorentzian or something.  But your data has that low `x` shoulder that definitely does not look like your uncited figure.

Comment: Yes I see your point. Trying other model forms was useful - a Voigt model for the fit seems to be the best in this case.